# Python Pandas pivot_table - Count of values in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a DataFrame (28 rows from the Titanic passenger list) which has a column "Sex" consisting of two values, "Male", "Female". I want to get the count of Males/Females

The output should show "Sex" as Row labels(index) and the count (of Male/Female) in the second column

```
df.pivot_table(index ="Sex", values ="Sex", aggfunc='count')
```

This returns a "ValueError: Grouper for 'Sex' not 1-dimensional" error.

Please guide

Comment: Can you please paste the dataframe into the question?

Comment: If you need assistance formatting a small sample of your DataFrame as a copyable piece of code for SO see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: df.pivot_table(index ="Sex",values="PassengerId", aggfunc='count') - This works and gives the result(i.e. when the index and values are different fields. Can it not be done with only the "Sex" column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just `df['Sex'].value_counts()`

Comment: Thanks, This does answer the question and gives the expected result. What would be pivot_table version of the solution?

Comment: @user1955215 there isn't one. Look at `df.pivot_table(columns="sex", aggfunc='count')` and then look at `df.pivot_table(index="sex", aggfunc='count')`. You'll see that you can't have the same column value for both index and values.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, Thanks for the clarification regarding "you cant have the same column value".